# Passing encoded XML content in SOAP envelop request in Java application

Tags: soap, java-8, cxf

I'm developing a Java application where I need to make a web service request using SOAP protocol. In that SOAP envelop request, one of the XML attribute/property called **content** will hold the XML file itself like below:-

```
<n1:envelope>
        <message>
            <id>67872894892424</id>
        </message>
        <sender agency="GS1" scheme="tGLK">ur.0</sender>
        <recipients>
            <id agency="GS1" scheme="tGLK">test</id>
        </recipients>
        <content encoding="XML" extension="A" format="ATTP">
------
----
</content></n1:envelope>
```

I'm new to it and requires some assistance in clarifying my doubts. I'm using JDK1.8 and Apache CXF. How can I do marshaling/unmarshalling for this particular content attribute? Normal SOAP envelops request is easy to do it but not sure how to pass an encoded XML itself in SOAP request. Is there any reference links? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your case is an example of including XML inside XML. Yes, XML could be included inside an SOAP(XML), there are two ways, though both means almost same thing.

> Using CDATA encoding

`<hello><![CDATA[<El><E2><E3 attr="D1">Text</E3></E2></El>]]></hello>`

> Converting the XML into text by replacing, `<` with `&lt;`, `"` with `&quote;` and `>` with `&gt;`

`<hello><El><E2><E3 attr="D1">Text</E3></E2></El></hello>`

To

`<hello>&gt;El&lt;&gt;E2&lt;&gt;E3 attr="D1"&lt;Text&gt;/E3&lt;&gt;/E2&lt;&gt;/El&lt;</hello>`

Hence, to include the XML inside SOAP, while adding the XML element, you need to follow either approach while marshaling/unmarshaling.